# Infragistics Windows Form error - "Object of type 'Infragistics.Win.Appearance' cannot be converted to type 'Infragistics.Win.AppearanceBase'."

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, infragistics

After I dragged and dropped an **Ultra Panel** in the form. 
It is showing:

> Object of type 'Infragistics.Win.Appearance' cannot be converted to type 'Infragistics.Win.AppearanceBase'.

Need help how to resolve?

Comment: Did you try to search for this error? [The first link](http://devcenter.infragistics.com/Support/KnowledgeBaseArticle.Aspx?ArticleID=9687) that popups show 9 workarounds for this problem. None of them fixes your problem?

Comment: No I tried all the steps but still unable to resolve this, also my solution is not building.

Comment: Check your references, I believe you may have multiple versions of the Infragistics controls referenced.

Comment: @Steve  None of them fixed mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds as though there are multiple versions of the Infragistics assemblies referenced by your project.  If this is the case, the solution is to make sure that all of the Infragistics references are to the same version of the toolset.  Often this is done by removing the references to the version that has less references.